# What is the equivalents of matlab's pcolor in R?

Tags: matlab, r, statistics, machine-learning

I have a 16x16 matrix of grayscale values representing handwriting digits. Is there a plot in R that I can use to visualize it?

Matlab has pcolor, I am looking for something along those lines.
[pcolor](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to go to extra packages. Base R already has this, see

- `help(image)`
- `help(heatmap)`

and Romain's excellent [R Graph Gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/) which has a searchable index.

Answer (score 3):

There are many options for something like this.  One option is to use the `geom_tile` in ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melt(volcano), aes(x=X1, y=X2, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
```

Ends up looking like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [had.co.nz](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/graphics/75407db4900d5077b412310bc4956cb0.png))</sub>

Some other options include: `levelplot` (in lattice) or `color2D.matplot` (in plotrix).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was hoping to use ggplot2, so this is a good excuse.